# "Syntax error: "(" unexpected invoke-rc.d:" when installing the i8kutils package

Tags: dpkg

When I install same application get that error;

```
Setting up i8kutils (1.41) ...  
/etc/init.d/i8kmon: 1:
/etc/default/i8kmon: Syntax error: "(" unexpected  invoke-rc.d:
initscript i8kmon, action "start" failed.  dpkg: error processing
package i8kutils (--configure):  subprocess installed
post-installation script returned error exit status 2 
E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Looks like it may be a bug in i8kutils. Doing a search turned up a lot of Debian bug reports with the same syntax error, but for version 1.21. Report it on Luanchpad.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem must be solved by loading the `i8k.ko` module at start-up.

Comment: You might want to expand this answer to explain how to do that.